# Does Amazon AWS EC2 Container Service support volumes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html) suggests not. There is more information on their [task definition page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_defintions.html), including a mysql example, where a data volume is usually a reasonably good idea i.e.:

```
{
  "image": "mysql",
  "name": "db",
  "cpu": 10,
  "memory": 500,
  "essential": true,
  "entryPoint": [
    "/entrypoint.sh"
  ],
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
      "value": "pass"
    }
  ],
  "portMappings": []
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, [see the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_defintions.html#using_data_volumes). They are configured as a part of an ECS Task Definition. Here is [an article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-container-service-ecs-update-access-private-docker-repos-mount-volumes-in-containers/?sc_campaign=launch&sc_category=container_service&sc_channel=SM&sc_content=data_vol&sc_detail=std&sc_medium=aws&sc_publisher=twitter&adbsc=social_launches_20150220_40803576&adbid=568579747715788800&adbpl=tw&adbpr=66780587) describing how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are not supported at the moment. But AWS seems to be working on this feature.

https://twitter.com/mndoci/status/549647072358440964

Comment: This answer was right at that moment but is obsolete now.